# What is the default FPU of ARMv8 (also known as AArch64 or ARM64)?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm, arm64, neon

In several places it is said that the default FPU of ARMv8 is VFPv3/VFPv4 (they say so, but do not specify which one) and in others that it is NEON, and in some others it is still only "FPU". There is also talk that VFP has been deprecated, or that only its "vector" mode has. It's pretty confusing. Therefore, I would like to know:

What is the default FPU of ARMv8? I know we can choose between VFP and NEON, but I would like to know which one is the default one.

Also, based on the executed instruction, does a different unit execute the instruction? For example... Is the FADD instruction executed by the VFP even though NEON is the default FPU? And if not, will the statement be converted to an ADD.F32?

This doubt was even worse when I realized that there are NEON scalar instructions!

One last thing, if NEON and VFP are no longer coprocessors in ARMv8, and their instructions were added to the default instruction set, then how does it work?

I know there are many questions, but they are all related to the same question.

Any and all help is welcome, and if you don't understand something from the question I'll be happy to detail.

Comment: Which operating mode do you mean?  In AArch32 mode, the FPU is NEON/VFPv4.  In AArch64 mode, it's ASIMD, which is similar to NEON.  There might technically be a distinction between FPU and SIMD on AArch64, but as SIMD is architectural on general purpose computers, it is largely an academic one.

Comment: *if NEON and VFP are no longer coprocessors in ARMv8, and their instructions were added to the default instruction set, then how does it work?* - The same way it's worked for years; the FP execution units are built-in to the CPU, not a separate chip.  Being a "coprocessor" was just a matter of the programming interface, not the physical design of the CPU, ever since chips could hold enough transistors to make integrating the FP (and SIMD) execution units make sense.

Comment: Note that AArch32 and AArch64 are different instruction sets supported by the ARMv8 architecture.  ARMv7 only supported AArch32.  The AArch64 instruction set is quite different from AArch64.  Read the ARMv8 Architecture Reference Manual to learn more!

Comment: @fuz I'm mean AArch64. ARM tends to talk about Neon and AdvSIMD interchangeably, so there is some confusion there, but I know that the SIMD engine of ARMv8 A.K.A. AdvSIMD is an evolution of the ARMv7's Neon. So you're telling me that the floating-point instructions are executed in AdvSIMD? Also, in AArch32, is VFPv4 the default? Because speaking "NEON/VFPv4" is kinda redundant. Also also, the reference manual are really vague in this aspect!

Comment: @PeterCordes oh, I get it. In this case the unit still takes care of the execution of the instruction.

Comment: Also, I just remembered, in some places they talk about "FPU with or without NEON". This really adds to the confusion! This is ARM itself calling AdvSIMD Neon.

Comment: @boltragons Could you link the places where this is claimed?

Comment: based on history one should also understand that there is the architecture and then there is the product and then there is the vendor.   the vendor can remove the fpu.  the architecture defines the maximum, where as the product might not have every feature or may make some of them an option.    in the 32 bit days the fpu was not standard, you could buy one but also you could glue your own on as it was a coprocessor, I dont know if armv8-a is similar in that respect.  and as mentioned the 64 and 32 bit cores are completely incompatible so I would not expect any fpu conversation to be either.

Comment: @fuz Here: https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/10/11/demystifying-arm-floating-point-compiler-options/

Comment: @boltragons The article seems correct, but most of what it talks about applies to AArch32 only.  Note that even with ARMv8, VFP is still a coprocessor.  If it wasn't, it would have different opcodes.  A coprocessor is a specific concept within the design of the ARM architecture and does not imply anything about how the CPU works internally.

Comment: @fuz Everywhere it's said that the VFP and NEON (brand name for Advanced SIMD) doesn't follow the "coprocessor" design anymore, as it's instructions are incorpored in the instruction set. So VFP and NEON must be like units inside the processor. But my real doubt is really what FPU is used in ARMv8. I searched the manuals and found NOTHING about this. Is VFP used in AArch32 and AdvSIMD used in AArch64? Like, if I execute FADD, which unit will execute this?

Comment: @boltragons As far as the instruction encoding is concerned, VFP3 is still a coprocessor.  I don't really know about NEON though.  As for which unit an instruction executes on, that's an implementation detail of the CPU.  AArch64 likely uses the same units internally as AArch32.  ASIMD is entirely new and does not use the VFP branding.  There is no continuity.

Answer (score 2):

The architecture defines instruction encodings - i.e. instruction bit patterns and what they must do. It also defines groupings for specific features - i.e. if you claim Advanced SIMD support you must implement this set of instructions.

The architecture has no concept of hardware units that process instructions. This is entirely implementation-defined behavior for a specific microarchitecture. Can scalar-fp and vector-fp run on the same hardware pipelines? Yes. Can they run on totally different hardware pipelines? Yes.

Ignore the coprocessor-style encoding of the original VFP instructions - it's a historical quirk dating back to ARM9 and ARM11. Today it's just an instruction bit pattern like any other and doesn't imply any specific implementation.

Given that your concerns are mostly just implementation detail - what's the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you care which unit things run on?